# bash equivalent to csh alias that has arguments and pipes

Tags: bash, csh

I'm a long-time Unix and `csh` user. I typically have this alias in my `.cshrc` file on my Mac OS computer. It does an `ls` with an argument and then pipes it through `less`.

```
alias   dir        "ls -laF -G \!* | less -rEX"
```

I'm using a new system with `bash`. How would I write the equivalent alias in `bash` to put into my `.bashrc` file?

I've [read](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/) that I need to create a `function()`, but the arguments and piping are not clear to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try: `dir() { ls -laF -G "$@" | less -rEX; }`

Comment: Can you explain the csh cyntax to us poor bash users?

Comment: @anubhava: That's slick. If you post that comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use a shell function in `bash` than `alias` which has many drawbacks. This function should work for you:

```
dir() {
    ls -laF -G "$@" | less -rEX
}
```